# What are the different ways to push a page down using Javascript, CSS or Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

**I'm creating a chrome extension and I want to reserve space for my iframe toolbar that is appended outside the body**

I tried the following with many websites, I inspect the page html with Firebug, go to the body tag and add this css rule to it :

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
```

I see he whole page is pushed down by 40px.

I cannot use `margin-top:40px` It doesn't seem to work properly it doesn't push down fixed elements.

Is there another way I can do to achieve the same thing using another technique, using Jquery or Javascript code ?

Comment: There are probably lots of different ways, making this a difficult question to answer. Are you wanting to move the entire body, or just [scroll it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scrollTo)?

Comment: Wouldn't `body { margin-top: 40px }` do what you need?

Comment: why don't you just add `margin-bottom` to your iframe toolbar?

Comment: I want to move the entire body down by 40px; -webkit-transform works fine but it causes some problems with facebook chat, please login to facebook from google chrome and try to add that css ruled I mentioned above and you will see the problem

Comment: @ShikataGaNai Unfortunately there's no generic method to get around this. You have to write a specific style for Facebook. For example, `#blueBar {top:40px;} body{padding-top:40px;}` does the trick.

Comment: body { position: relative; top: 40px; } ?

Comment: If it's only 40px, as workaround, you could use `translateY` with  `transform:scaleY(scale_number);`. But it won't be pixel clean.